# How to use FetchMode.JOIN with JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot, JPA and Hibernate. I have the following entity `User`, which has a relation to `roles`:

```
@Table
public class User {

    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // ...

}
```

When I read a User, hibernate generates one select for each attached role instead of using a Join. In pure Hibernate I would solve this issue by adding

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect here.

Is there a possibility to set the preferred fetch mode for all queries regarding this entity?

One workaround I found, and I really consider this a workaround, because I would need to specify it for each and every query, is this:

```
public List<User> findById(long userId){

        Specification<User> spec = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
        {
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
            root.fetch("roles", JoinType.LEFT);
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), userId);
        };

        return repository.findAll(spec);
    }
```

Comment: There is no portable way to force fetch mode in JPA. That being said, I'm surprised `@Fetch` has no effect, it really should work in this case.

Comment: @crizzis I believe when using Criteria-based queries, `@FetchMode` might be ignored.  It might only apply when using find-by-id.

Comment: Tim, have you tried using `@BatchSize`?

Comment: @Naros I thought the OP meant `@Fetch` had no effect *at all*, but maybe it is not the case

Comment: Yes, I meant `@Fetch` has no effect. I thought this is because we use JPA classes/annotations and just mixing hibernate annotations in had no effect, but you sound like I'm wrong. And yes I used `repository.findById` before, not Criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

Very late on this,
but you need to define a join between parent entity and related entity

```
Join<MyEntity, RelatedEntity> join = root.join("relatedEntity");
root.fetch("relatedEntity");
```